# Is there any way to get actual language fonts from Google speech to text output?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, speech-to-text

I am using Xamarin Android C# and I am using below code
https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/PlatformFeatures/SpeechToText

It converts speech into text but it gives output in English fonts only. Is there any way to get/convert this output in that particular languages' font?

Example: It gives output for the Hindi language: mera naam kya he

Requirement: मेरा नाम क्या है

I can use Java or C#. So I have added both the tags.

Comment: Is this help? [Setp 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/speech#step-2---finding-the-languages-available) and [Step 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/speech#step-4---testing-and-loading-new-languages)